# Lua - Error in execution of return and or

Tags: debugging, error-handling, lua

I am basically doing some testing to get to know the Lua language a bit better. I found a bug that makes zero sense to me.

Function:

```
local function d(c)
    return (!c and print("c", false) or print("c", true))
end

local function a(b, c)
    return (!b and d(c) or print("b", true))
end
```

When i run `a(1, nil)` or `a(1, 1)` it outputs `b true`, but if i run `a(nil, 1)` then it outputs `c true` and `b true`

If anyone could enlighten me on why it returns two value when that technically shouldn't be possible?

Comment: You are confusing return values with printed output.  On top of that you *can* return multiple values in Lua.

Comment: I know that it is possible to return multiple values in lua, but for this case it should choose either, not both. But thanks for explaining why i experienced this bug.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you already understand what's happening, but I've already written this post. Lua doesn't have a `!` operator; I guess you meant `not`. (I wouldn't be surprised if someone has made a patched version of Lua with `!` in place of `not`.)

`a(nil, 1)` returns `not nil and d(1) or print("b", true)`. Now, `not nil` evaluates to `true` and `d(1)` evaluates to `nil`, so we have `true and nil or print("b", true)`, which in turn evaluates to `nil or print("b", true)`, and therefore `print("b", true)` is evaluated.

As to why `d(1)` evaluates to nil: it returns `not 1 and print("c", false) or print("c", true)`. That is equivalent to `not 1 and nil or nil` because `print` always returns nothing when it is called, and nothing is treated as `nil` by the operators `and` and `or`. `not x and nil or nil` always evaluates to `nil` whether `x` is truthy or falsy, so `d` always returns nil. (The only difference is that if `d` receives a falsy value, both `print` calls are evaluated.)

You can verify that `print` returns nothing by calling `type(print('a'))`: it throws the error "bad argument #1 to 'type' (value expected)", whereas `type(nil)` returns `"nil"`.